# What's the namespace, soap action and url should be for my android app accessing wcf web service?

Tags: android, ksoap2

My WSDL is like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions name="ABCWcfService" targetNamespace="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService/Imports">
          <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://desktop/ABCWcfService/ABCWcfService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService"/>
          <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://desktop/ABCWcfService/ABCWcfService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
        </xsd:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="IABCWcfService_GetWhatsOnData_InputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWhatsOnData"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="IABCWcfService_GetWhatsOnData_OutputMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetWhatsOnDataResponse"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:portType name="IABCWcfService">
        <wsdl:operation name="GetWhatsOnData">
          <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService/IABCWcfService/GetWhatsOnData" message="tns:IABCWcfService_GetWhatsOnData_InputMessage"/>
          <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService/IABCWcfService/GetWhatsOnDataResponse" message="tns:IABCWcfService_GetWhatsOnData_OutputMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
      <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IABCWcfService" type="tns:IABCWcfService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="GetWhatsOnData">
          <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService/IABCWcfService/GetWhatsOnData" style="document"/>
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
          </wsdl:output>
         </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="ABCWcfService">
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IABCWcfService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IABCWcfService">
          <soap:address location="http://desktop/ABCWcfService/ABCWcfService.svc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

I am wondering what should I put for my SOAP_ACTION, METHOD_NAME, NAMESPACE and URL?
I guess:

```
SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService/IABCWcfService/GetWhatsOnData"
METHOD_NAME = "GetWhatsOnData"
NAMESPACE = "http://www.ABC.com/ABCWcfService"
URL = "http://desktop/ABCWcfService/ABCWcfService.svc"
```

But it seems not working in my code:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

It goes into exception at line androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); the exception object e has value null.

I have add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

in the Manifest file

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any good tutorial or code sample with both wcf web service also the ksoap2 access client for reference?

Comment: you got the solution for this issue?

Comment: First Add a / after the namespace and try

Comment: This is a offtopic, but instead of trying to create code for web service connection manually, you can try to use some online generator which will speed up your work. Personally I've used http://easywsdl.com and I had working code in a few seconds. You can also find other online generators if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCFTestClient and click on XML tab in bottom. You can find the information your are looking (SOAP URL and Action). I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

well im doing it like this

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "/Login?ID={ID}&PASSWORD={PASSWORD}")]
    System.IO.Stream ValidarLogin(int ID, string PASSWORD);
```

and in the android client

```
class MiTareaAsincrona extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    ProgressDialog dialog=null;


 protected void onPreExecute() {
   dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainScreen.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Verificando sus datos.. ");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
   // dialog.setMax(100);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();

    }


   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


       final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       final EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     String Cedula=  text1.getText().toString();
     String Password = text2.getText().toString();


     final String URL = "https://MYURL.COM/NGLOGIN/NGLogin.svc/Login?ID="+Cedula+"&PASSWORD="+Password;

    if(!Cedula.equals("") || !Password.equals("")){

                try {
                        key=ValidarLogin(URL);


                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        key="noinet";
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    //  this.cancel(true);
    }

    return key;

   }




   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       String a= result.toString();
       Boolean aa= " ".equals(result);

      if(!result.equals("false") & !result.equals("noinet")){
          dialog.dismiss();
         finalizo=true;
         if(finalizo){
              Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                intent.putExtra("llave", key);
                startActivity(intent);}
```

ValidarLogin(URL) code:

```
public String ValidarLogin (String URL) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
   {

       Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

       HttpClient  client =  new MyHttpsClient(getApplicationContext());

       HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL);
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

       int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

       if(status == 200) //sucess
       {
           HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
           String key = EntityUtils.toString(e);
         // get.abort();
        /*/ char[] arreglo = key.toCharArray();
         char[] arreglo2= new char[arreglo.length-2];

         for(int x=1; x<arreglo.length-1;x++){

             arreglo2[x-1] = arreglo[x];

         }

         /*/

           if(!key.equals("")){return key;}
           return "false";

       }

           return "false";


   }
```

the wcf returns a 1 or nothing depeding if the user and password are ok..

hope this helps you